# How can I remove tags from content results wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to bring some results with the get_the_excerpt().

In some point I have a result like this. I want to remove the  tags in the result

**This is the text I get:**

Cricket World Cup Winners Cricket World Cup Winners : An info-graphic by the team at AsiaBet.org Embed Cricket World Cup Winners on Your Site: Copy and Paste the Code Below https://www.asiabet.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/CWC_ALL1.jpg” alt=”Cricket World Cup Winners – Asiabet.org”>https://www.asiabet.org/cricket-world-cup-infographic/”>Cricket World Cup Winners by Asiabet.org 2015 only means one thing – the ICC Cricket World...

**My code**

```
$result = get_the_excerpt();

if ($result != '') {
    echo $result . '...'.'<br><br>';
} else {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo get_post_field('description', $post_id);
} ?>
```

Comment: use:   $result= strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());

Comment: `strip_tags()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: That was my first act but somehow it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\\[.*.\\]/', '', 'Cricket World Cup Winners [Info-graphic] [hupso] Cricket World Cup Winners : An info-graphic by the team at AsiaBet.org Embed Cricket World Cup Winners on Your Site: Copy and Paste the Code Below Cricket World Cup Winners by Asiabet.org 2015 only means one thing – the ICC Cricket', -1, $count);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use strip_shortcodes( $result );

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:-

```
$result= strip_tags(get_the_excerpt());  
$find = array('/\\[.*.\\]/', '/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i','[”]','[alt=Cricket World Cup Winners – >>]');
$result = preg_replace($find, '',$result, -1, $count);

if ($result != '') {
    echo $result . '...'.'<br><br>';
} else {
$post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo get_post_field('description', $post_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you It removed only [Info-graphic] [hupso]. So should I use a regex also for the image tags?

Comment: Do you want to remove image tag?

Comment: sorry no I saw that my post wasn't right. check it if you want again

Comment: Its working according to you. is there any problem now?

Comment: I want to remove also this phrase  <img src=”https://www.asiabet.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/CWC_ALL1.jpg” alt=”Cricket World Cup Winners – Asiabet.org”></br><a href=”https://www.asiabet.org/cricket-world-cup-infographic/”>. thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove all the image tag or you just want to get url from img, anchor tag.

Comment: all the image tag

Comment: Did you check the code it is removing all that you want. If you want more please tell me.

Comment: it removed only the content on [] and not the image tags.. I dont know why

Comment: there is something wrong.Please show me you content?

Comment: Updated code will remove all that you want from above text that you given

Answer (score 0):

To remove any shortcode like `[Info-graphic]`. you must define this shortcode in your theme otherwise it will act as string and you can replace this by using any php function i.e str_replace()
You can add given shortcode by following:

```
function shortcode_function( $atts ) {
    return "1234567890";
}
add_shortcode( 'Info-graphic', 'shortcode_function' );

$result = 'this is shortcode [Info-graphic]';
strip_shortcodes( $result );
```

This function will work.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a build in function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).